# powershell commands to get the metrics for the performance of VM

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, cloud

I am trying to get the metrics for the performance of the virtual machine like CPU utilisation, disk read troughput etc., in azure I want to get that by programmatically by invoking powershell commands but I am not getting the powershell commands as per the new release of azure i.e IaaS. please help me in this.. 
waiting for the reply.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is PowerShell for this type of actions. Especially for IaaS. The PaaS story is that you [configure the monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433052.aspx) metrics you want to follow, then read them from Table Storage (useful [references here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx)). This is just one of the advatages of the PaaS world. And the existing PowerShell cmdLets will help you to some extend - i.e. download perf. counters data. And that's it.

While in the IaaS you have to take care of your own monitoring and tracking mechanism, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to an Azure VM scale set environment, so I can't properly test for you, otherwise I would, and I also have no experience with a full IaaS environment, and my experience automating with performance counters is less than intermediate, but I'll at least offer what little I do know and hope it has relevance for you.

You mentioned read throughput - I don't know what OS(s) you're attempting to poll when you "invoke commands", but if they're Windows instances and *presumably* Windows Server 2012 or later, then you will have to enable disk metrics before they're available anywhere, in our case, to CIM and PowerShell.

Running this command will enable disk metrics and counters: `diskperf.exe /Y`.

NOTE: It's recommended to run this command's inverse when not in use (`diskperf.exe /N`) to disable disk counters and avoid performance issues.

Since I don't have the IaaS experience to fully comprehend what you might be working with, I'll start with assuming we were wanting to, let's say, enumerate and measure instances of disks and their performance metrics via PowerShell on Windows machines, which we might do with the following:

```
$physicalDiskCounters = Get-Counter -ListSet PhysicalDisk
$physicalDiskCounters | Get-Counter -Continuous -SampleInterval 2 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CounterSamples #| Direct to log/service/event, etc.
```

Is any of this relevant to your IaaS environment and PowerShell version/configuration? Are the cmdlets and their module absent entirely, or do they function differently that one would expect from the above?

Since I only have E5 licensing for 365, I can't go farther in experimenting for you, however, are the cmdlets like Get-Counter (or their module) absent in your OS environments or do they just function differently than they do in Windows PowerShell? If it's only disk metrics failing when trying to get counters from Windows Server instances, try running `diskperf.exe /Y` before your polling and then `diskperf.exe /N` after.